# libstdc++ both statically and dynamically linked through different libraries

Tags: c++, static-linking, dynamic-linking, libstdc++

1. My executable dynamically links two libraries (d1.so  and d2.so).
2. d1.so statically links to libstdc++.
3. d2.so dynamically links to libstdc++.

Assuming d1.so is loaded first, which stdlib (dynamic or static) method will get called in following scenarios,

1. d1.so makes a call to stdlib method.
2. d2.so makes a call to stdlib method.
3. Executable makes a  call to stdlib method.

If both d1.so and d2.so are compiled by different compiler versions, can it cause problems in runtime due to mixing of stdlib?

Comment: Note usually static linking will only include parts of the library, unless something like `-Wl,--whole-archive` is used.

Comment: Try not to do that.

Comment: I do not believe libstdc++ supports mixing static and dynamic linking at all.

Comment: I don't have control over d1.so and d2.so. My executable needs these two .so files. How to avoid linking problems.

Comment: If absolutely there is no proper way to handle the runtime headache, who is to blame? Is it d1.so (that statically links to libstdc++) or d2.so ?

Comment: Are you actually _experiencing_ any problems?

Comment: @paul sanders : Yes, stringstream operator << does not work when I include d1.so first and then include d2.so. It works if I change the order. 

I suspect it is due to stdc++. However, I'm not sure if it is due to version mismatch or linker issue etc.

Comment: @KarthickS I think you are in territory where you have to analyse and fix stuff yourself. In my opinion the fault is with `d1.so`. Even if you get it to compile, what is to guarantee that you won't end up with mismatching function implementations from the different library versions? I don't think guarantees are made for compatibility beyond ABI at the library boundary. Or did `d1.so` link the libstdc++ as hidden and private to itself? But I don't expect that to be supported either. Libstdc++ assumes ownership over certain resources such as stdout for std::cout that would certainly interfere.

Comment: what is `d1.so` and `d2.so` actually? What exactly does it mean that `operator << does not work" ? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is there really no prospect of getting a dynamically linked version of `d1.so`?  One can always ask the library maintainers, or build it yourself if you have the source code.